# SSRS using Business Development Studio and FetchXML

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, bids

I have the following Fetchxml for a Custom report to get all the Active Leads:

```
<fetch distinct="false" mapping="logical" output-format="xml-platform" version="1.0">
<entity name="lead" >
    <attribute name="companyname" />
    <attribute name="leadid" />
    <attribute name="gr_totaltraveldays" />
    <attribute name="gr_marketvertical" />
    <attribute name="leadsourcecode" />
    <attribute name="lastname" />
    <attribute name="firstname" />
    <attribute name="estimatedamount" />
    <attribute name="gr_dayssincelastactivity" />
    <attribute name="new_numberofattendees" />
    <attribute name="ownerid" />
    <order descending="false" attribute="ownerid" />
    <filter type="and" >
        <condition attribute="statecode" value="0" operator="eq" />
    </filter>
</entity>
```

I got this `FetchXML` from `Advance Find` in CRM 2011.
When i use this FetchXML in my report DataSet I get below error:

[image]

The `gr_totaltraveldays` field is there. I looked into the Database for fields and this field is in `LeadExtensionBase` table.

Comment: are you 100% sure that you are targeting the same CRM organization of that advanced find result?

Comment: @GuidoPreite yes I double checked everything. Could it be a problem that `gr_totaltraveldays` is in LeadExtensionBase table ??

Comment: the custom fields inside crm 2011 are always in the extension table, is not for that

Comment: try writing SQL query and running the report if Fetch XML is not a requirement. Or just test by querying gr_totaltraveldays in SQL and check whether it creates an issue through SQL report.

Comment: yeah that's what I did in the end:`with SQL query` but still wondering why `fetchxml` not working.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem in BIDS with FetchXML.i was getting the error : "The attribute "XXXX" cannot be found for entity "XX". Specify a valid query, and try again." However, the field existed in the entity and was published.

The solution was to change the connection string, adding the organization name, in the Datasource as following: **{URL};{organizationName};**
then it worked!

for example : https://XXXX.crm4.dynamics.com;org12345ab;

You can find the organizationname in the Settings --> Customization --> Deveoper resources.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Check your connection string. I had the same problem with my report.Seems like your connection string is explicitly pointing to the right organisation.
https://aaaa.crm4.dynamics.com;

This should work